# Why doesn't rails.vim recognize any gems that I install?

Tags: ruby, vim, rails.vim

I'm a ruby and vim newbie. I recently installed the rails.vim plugin and all the commands work fine apart from the commands to create a new Rails project. Every time I do this it says rails is not installed on my system, but it is! It also acts up when I create a class that requires a gem that I've installed. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Maybe you should add more details about your evironment: Are you using RVM? What OS are you using? If you issue the project creation scripts in the console, do they work?

Comment: Sorry about that, im using mac osx lion. If i issue the project creation scripts in the console they work. The problem seems to be with the rails.vim plugin somehow.

Comment: Try to take a look at the rails.vim help, to see if there is any configuration that needs to be taken. //  To use the help, see :help add-local-help.  In a nutshell, :helptags ~/.vim/doc. For details, see :help rails

Answer (score 0):

Did you `rvm use system` before building / `brew install`-ing macvim? I didn't and got many errors. Doing `rvm use system` beforehand fixed things up for me.